# Observable of pipe shareReplay vs. ReplaySubject.observableOf

Tags: angular, rxjs6

shareReplay isn't working like I would expect. From the documentation I would expect the following bits of code to be equivalent.

```
@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root'
} )
export class CartService {

    private list: InventoryItem[] = [];
    cart: Observable<ReadonlyArray<Readonly<InventoryItem>>> = of( this.list ).pipe(
        shareReplay( 1 )
    );

    constructor() {}

    addItem( item: InventoryItem ) {
        this.list.push( item );
    }
}
```

and

```
@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root'
} )
export class CartService {

    private list: InventoryItem[] = [];
    private subject = new ReplaySubject<ReadonlyArray<Readonly<InventoryItem>>>(1);
    cart: Observable<ReadonlyArray<Readonly<InventoryItem>>> = this.subject.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    addItem( item: InventoryItem ) {
        this.list.push( item );
        this.subject.next(this.list);
    }
}
```

Yet only the second version works where all subscribers receive the events when `addItem(...)` is called.

The first example only works in one instance in my root component, but not in any other component where I use a similar syntax.

```
[matBadge]="(cartService.cart | async)?.length"
```

I've verified that only one instance of the service is being created, can anyone give me some insight on what's going on in the first piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are not the same.

```
private list: InventoryItem[] = [];
    cart: Observable<ReadonlyArray<Readonly<InventoryItem>>> = of( this.list ).pipe(
        shareReplay( 1 )
    );
```

`of(this.list)` will take **current** `this.list` and when you subscribe you get the list but you won't get the list again if you do `this.list.push(...)`. You would have to subscribe again.

On the other hand when you signal change in the list using Subject, your subscribers will get notified again.

So this is critical:

```
this.subject.next(this.list);
```

Comment: I see, I had assumed `this.list.push(...)` would trigger observable changes. Instead I only pushed the reference to the list once. The reason my root component worked is it was the only one that wasn't using `OnPush` change detection.